# How to check UsernameToken with derived key only?

Tags: jax-ws, ws-security, wss4j

With servers, how can I check clients use derived key or not?

I'm working on a JAX-WS project with WSS4J.

I managed to make some code working in UsernameToken with password derived key (salt+iteration).

1. Server generates username/password and give them to clients
2. Clients access endpoints with those information.

And I want to force clients to use the way of password derived only

**NOT ALLOWED**

```xml
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="Example-1">
  <wsse:Username> ... </wsse:Username>
  <wsse:Password Type="..."> ... </wsse:Password>
  <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="..."> ... </wsse:Nonce>
  <wsu:Created> ... </wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
```

**MUST BE**

```xml
<wsse:UsernameToken wsse:Id="…">
  <wsse:Username>…</wsse:Username>
  <wsse11:Salt>…</wsse11:Salt>
  <wsse11:Iteration>…</wsse11:Iteration>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
```

Can I actually force them?

How can I check it in my Handler?

Can anybody please show me how to do with WSS4J?